# multiple boost io_service for multiple network cards on separate threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, boost-asio

I have available multiple network cards on the pc I am working on. I'd like to use a thread per each network card to achieve better performance. My application will receive UDP traffic from multiple sources that I want to group across these network cards/threads.

With such architecture in mind, if use `boost::asio` does make sense to have multiple `boost::asio::io_service` objects, each running on a separate thread assigned to a single network card?

Essentially a single `boost::asio::io_service` will run in a thead to  execute all asynchronous methods for all UDP sockets binding on the same network card.

Is this a good idea to process the network traffic received on each card independently?

```
NIC A  --->    boost::io_service nic_a;

               socket one(nic_a);
               one.bind(nic_a, 0);

               socket two(nic_a);
               two.bind(nic_a);

               // all sockets call async_read

-------------------------------------------------------
               nic_a.run(); /// call this in Thread #a
-------------------------------------------------------

NIC B  --->    boost::io_service nic_b;

               socket three(nic_b);
               three.bind(nic_b, 0);

               socket four(nic_b);
               four.bind(nic_b);

               // all sockets call async_read

-------------------------------------------------------
               nic_b.run(); /// call this in Thread #b
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `io_service` in a thread per pair of network cards, you may be better off wrapping your sockets in an `asio::io_service::strand` and using a single `io_service` in a thread pool, see: [Strands: Use Threads Without Explicit Locking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) and [Asynchronous IO with boost asio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwOv_tw2eA4).

It is easiest to put the `sockets` and `strands` together in a class as in this example: [Timer 5 example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html). There is some code that supports `asio` UDP sockets and `strands` [here](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib/tree/master/include/via/comms).

Comment: after having spent some time in studying the topic I think that it was a good suggestion. I had the wrong understanding of how ASIO works; once I read the material I started appreciating it very much.